# moving diagonally makes player go faster

Tags: python, pygame, pygame2

I have this simple script for movement.

```py
if x > 0:
    if key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        rect_player.move_ip(-1 * speed, 0)
if x < SCREEN_WIDTH - 110:
    if key[pygame.K_d] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        rect_player.move_ip(speed, 0)
if y > 0:
    if key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]:
        rect_player.move_ip(0, -1 * speed)
if y < SCREEN_HEIGHT - 110:
    if key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        rect_player.move_ip(0, speed)
```

When the player travels in one direction, everything goes fine. But when they travel diagonally, it goes faster. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: For the diagonal you have to multiply the speed with `1/math.sqrt(2)` (~0.707). However, [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) objects can just store integral data. So it's not that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) is supposed to represent an area on the screen, a `pygame.Rect` object can only store integral data (the decimal places are lost when you assign a floating point number).

> The coordinates for Rect objects are all integers. [...]

I recommend to use [`pygame.math.Vector2`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2) for the problem. Store the position of the object in a `pygame.math.Vector2` object:

```py
pos = pygame.math.Vector2(start_x, start_y)
```

Set a direction vector depending on the keys. Scale the vector to the length of `speed` with [`scale_to_length`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.scale_to_length). Move the object and update `rect_player`:

```py
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
up = key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]
down = key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_DOWN]
left = key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_LEFT]
right = key[pygame.K_d] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]

move = pygame.math.Vector2(right - left, down - up)
if move.length_squared() > 0:
    move.scale_to_length(speed)
    pos += move  
    rect_player.topleft = round(pos.x), round(pos.y)
```

---

If you don't care about the floating point accuracy just move the rectangle:

```py
key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
up = key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]
down = key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_DOWN]
left = key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_LEFT]
right = key[pygame.K_d] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]

move = pygame.math.Vector2(right - left, down - up)
if move.length_squared() > 0:
    move.scale_to_length(speed)
    rect_player.move_ip(round(move.x), round(move.y))
```

---

Minimal example:

[image]

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rect_player = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
rect_player.center = window.get_rect().center
speed = 5

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False      

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    up = key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]
    down = key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_DOWN]
    left = key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_LEFT]
    right = key[pygame.K_d] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]

    move = pygame.math.Vector2(right - left, down - up)
    if move.length_squared() > 0:
        move.scale_to_length(speed)
        rect_player.move_ip(round(move.x), round(move.y))       

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), rect_player)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

---

If you derive the velocity by `math.sqrt(2)` but continue to use a `pygame.Rect`, it still does not lead to an accurate movement. pygame.Rect objects (`rect_player`) can only store integral values (the decimal places are lost when you assign a floating point number). Therefore this works only approximately and fails completely if seed is a small value (e.g. 1). The only value for which the solution works really well is for `speed=10` because `10/math.sqrt(2)`, is 7.071 (~7).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Rabbid76 for helping me figure it out, but this worked out for me:

```py
count  = 0
if x > 0:
    if key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        count += 1
if x < SCREEN_WIDTH - 110:
    if key[pygame.K_d] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        count += 1
if y > 0:
    if key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]:
        count += 1
if y < SCREEN_HEIGHT - 110:
    if key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        count += 1

if count >= 2:
    speed = speed/math.sqrt(2)

if x > 0:
    if key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        rect_player.move_ip(-1 * speed, 0)
if x < SCREEN_WIDTH - 110:
    if key[pygame.K_d] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        rect_player.move_ip(speed, 0)
if y > 0:
    if key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]:
        rect_player.move_ip(0, -1 * speed)
if y < SCREEN_HEIGHT - 110:
    if key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        rect_player.move_ip(0, speed)
```

Comment: Your solution still does not lead to an accurate movement. `pygame.Rect` objects (`rect_player`) can only store integral values (the decimal places are lost when you assign a floating point number). Therefore your solution works only approximately and fails completely if `seed` is a small value (e.g. 1). The only value for which the solution works really well is for `speed=10` because `10/math.sqrt(2)`, is 7.07 (~7).